# In Google App Engine, given the kind of an entity, how can you fetch the Class for the kind?

Tags: google-app-engine

I would like to be able to retrieve a class from the class kind in the python version of Google App Engine. How do I retrive the class with a string containing the class kind?

```
player_props = Player.properties()
country_props = Country.properties()

model_list = ['Player', 'Country']

for m in model_list:
  #foo = theClass
  props =  foo.properties()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `class_for_kind("Kind")` function, in the `google.appengine.ext.db` package.  Your model classes must be imported for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, provided you've imported the model classes into your module, you could use the [`globals()` function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals):

```
for m in model_list:
    klass = globals()[m]
    props = klass.properties()
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know the module that the classes were loaded from, you can get the classes from the module.

```
import models

model_list = ['Player', 'Country']
for m in model_list:
    klass = getattr(models,  m)
    props = klass.properties()
```